I am trying to record audio on python without any losses
I am working on a project that requires realtime speech to text transcription and to do so I need to record audio continuosly.
Record 5 seconds of audio.
Every 5 seconds write it to a file
The file must be 10 seconds long so write the last 2 chunks
While doing this steps I realized that my python script takes a little bit more than 5 seconds to write to a file and it generally takes 5.06'ish so there is some loss and I want to get rid off the loss how do U do it.
The code that I attached is writing the audio to the file when there is an interrupt. And the code is from chatGPT
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from pydub import AudioSegment
import time as t
import os


seconds = 5
fs = 44100
recordsMaxLength = 2


def record_audio(seconds=seconds, fs=fs, recordsMaxLength=recordsMaxLength):
    audioIndex = 0
    current_time = 0
    records = []
    output_dir = "records"
    concatedRecords = None
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    try:
        for i in range(3):
            print("time between starts:", t.time()-current_time)
            record = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='int16')
            current_time = t.time()
            sd.wait()                   *****************************************************
            print("time: ", t.time() - current_time)
            current_time = t.time()
            if len(records) < recordsMaxLength:
                records.append(record)
            else:
                for i in range(recordsMaxLength - 1):
                    records[i] = records[i + 1]
                records[recordsMaxLength - 1] = record

            if len(records) > 1:
                concatedRecords = np.concatenate(records)

            audioIndex += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    # If there are no records, there's nothing to save
    if concatedRecords is not None:
        # Convert numpy array to pydub AudioSegment
        audio_segment = AudioSegment(
            data=concatedRecords.tobytes(),
            sample_width=concatedRecords.dtype.itemsize,
            frame_rate=fs,
            channels=2
        )

        # Export the AudioSegment as an MP3 file
        output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, "records.mp3")
        audio_segment.export(output_path, format="mp3")
        print(f"Saved recording as {output_path}")
    else:
        print("No audio recorded to save.")

With this code I've added timestamps to see what takes the time most and I've realized that the line with sd.wait() that I added asteriks to the line. Only this line spends time.

instead of using loop for i in range(recordsMaxLength - 1): records[i] = records[i + 1] you can do record.pop(0) to remove first element from list. And later you can still use append() to add new element at the end

I expect that sd.rec() runs in background. Normally it can be useful when you want to do something else at the same time - e.g. display GUI with button Cancel. In your code it needs to use sd.wait()to stop rest of code before data will be ready to use. I would rather check time for rest of code - np.concatenate and other code - because it may need your missing 0.06. You may try to run separate tread which only getssd.rec()` without running other code - so it will no need extra time for np.conatenate, etc.  - and other calculation do in current thread

Thanks for answers. I figured out another way. Since I can't get a realtime audio stream I thought that I could work with the 5 seconds that I have. I will look for a particular keyword every 5 seconds then I will record for lets say 10 seconds. So I changed my approach to the problem and I think it'll work. You can hit me up for the current state if you are interested or if you have any suggestions.
